# JPA Delete query not working

Tags: java, sql, jpa, entitymanager

Well, I do not understand why me code does not work. Could Someone please take a look. It does not provide any error messages but the Customer will not be deleted. Other methods are working well (getCustomerbyId, getAllCustomers and so)
Thanks

```
public void deleteCustomerById(long id) {
        EntityManager em = null;
        try {
            em = JpaUtil.getFactory().createEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            Query query = em.createQuery("Delete  from Customer c where c.id = :id");
            query.setParameter("id", id);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {
            JpaUtil.closeQuietly(em);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which DBMS you are using? that delete syntax is not supported in all DBMS

Comment: I am using HSQLDB. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to execute queries to have SQL issues to the database; in this case you will want to use executeUpdate() and get the modified row count to verify something was deleted or not.

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
Query query = em.createQuery("Delete  from Customer c where c.id = :id");
query.setParameter("id", id);
int rows = query.executeUpdate();
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a query but not executing it.
You should add

```
query.executeUpdate();
```

before committing

Answer (score 0):

Use jpa APis find(Customer.class) to find the customer object then use romove(object)

Comment: That would be appropriate if the entity has child-entities that must also be deleted, otherwise OP's one-query approach is better.